# Missing 64 bit support. Appstore Submission Error

Tags: ios, architecture, app-store, 64-bit, submission

I have seen some are having same question as mine. But let me tell u the solutions which I have tried

I am using iOS 8 SDK
I have added arm64 architecture both in standard architecture and valid architecture in both project and target.
One solution is to disconnect the device while submitting. But I can't do that. Because I have used Magtek for external accesorry hardware. Because of which I have to keep my device connected (Note: Device is 64 bit) .

If anyone have solution to this , I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried same with target and project build settings ? Set No to Build Active Architecture Only under both project & target build settings .

I don't think there have any issue with your 64 bit device connected .

Please see below attach image for more understanding.

[image]

Comment: Tried this... getting build failed... and it's not showing any error as well :(

Comment: build failed and not showing error , please check it again

Comment: So far I have tried your solution more than 10 times